# What's an elegant way to export objects in CoffeeScript module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have several functions in a CoffeeScript module:

```
func1 = () -> ...
func2 = () -> ...
func3 = () -> ...
func4 = () -> ...
```

If I want to make it clear where they come from (without searching for a definition), I'd avoid making them global (`@func1 = ...`, `@func2 = ...`) , and stick to a more explicit syntax:

```
helpers = require('/lib/helpers.coffee')
```

But this requires something like

```
meteor.exports.func1 = func1
```

repeated every time. Or

```
meteor.exports.func1 = () -> ...
```

But this way it's harder to make calls between them here inside.

I know ES6 has an elegant syntax like `{var1, var2, ...}`, but is there something similar in CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func1 = () ->
func2 = () ->
module.exports = {func1, func2}
```

compiled to:

```
var func1, func2;
func1 = function() {};
func2 = function() {};
module.exports = {
  func1: func1,
  func2: func2
};
```